# Most suitable Java Collection for duplicate elements

Tags: java, collections

I'm currently working on one project. I am trying to create a management system for a store. The problem is I need some sort of collection for stock, where while adding elements that already exist with the same name (updating the number of same item) it's state (attribute stockLevel) would update accordingly to the given quantity. Does anyone know which should be the best to let do such a thing? `Map`, `Set` or `List`?

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious a list isn't appropriate. Seems like a Set or a Map would make the most sense, no? It kind of depends on how you want to access it.

Comment: @DaveNewton there is mention of adding duplicated values. Set is by definition not appropriate for this case, at least without a more complex way do distinct elements than their name property.

Comment: Can you define your "state"? In particular, why is it embedded within the object?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak No, the requirement is that if you "add an item of the same name" that the record for that item is updated accordingly. E.g., lookup, if found, you're incrementing, say, a quantity. Each item (name, apparently) has associated values, and if you "add" an element to the structure, you're updating quantities, not necessarily adding a new item.

Comment: Ultimately you have two requirements here: how do I store the product's values, and how do I access them. What you need is a class that composites the backing store (e.g., a map or set), and a function that accepts a product and updates the backing store appropriately.

Comment: Still, Set wouldn't be the best candidate here. As @Slanec suggested, a Multiset or a Map with item as a key would be better and easier to use.

Comment: fge - by state I mean one of object's attributes - stockLevel. For example I want to add a product to my stock. I already have the same item in my stock with stockLevel of 20 (so I have 20 of them). I am adding another one and instead of adding new, I want to only update its stockLevel to 21. I am also thinking of doing it 'manually' by simply changing the state by choosing an object and updating stockLevel whenever I get a product, maybe this option would be better.

Answer (score 4):

That would [a multiset (a.k.a. a bag)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). You can easily roll your own implementation as a `Map<Item, Integer>`, or use one of the existing classes, e.g. Google Guava's [`Multiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html). Apache Commons Collections also have one, so do Eclipse Collections etc.

Answer (score 0):

> where while adding elements that already exist with the same name
>   (updating the number of same item) it's state (attribute stockLevel)
>   would update accordingly to the given quantity

In your usecase, `Map` is good to store the information :

`Map<Product, StockLevel>` for representing a map with as key `Product` and as value the number of it in stocks : `StockLevel`

For iterating on a Map, you could not keep the insertion order with a `HashMap` but for your need, it should not be a problem.

Nevertheless, if you want to keep the insertion order when you iterate on it or that you want that the map be ordered according to some needs (alphabetical or other), you can use more sophisticated map such as `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 0):

Set do not allow duplicate values, but this is not a solution. If you insert a duplicate value it will be ignored. You can choose a List of Items and then loop to find duplicates. An if condition can be added to increment it's state.

Comment: Why would you iterate over a list when you could look up the product in a set or map? There's no reason to keep multiple items around, just their associated data.